# VBA in Excel - Pasting to Active Cell then Tab Right

Tags: excel, with-statement, pasting, vba

I am needing a bit of assistance with Excel VBA. I am switching back and forth from Excel and another application and copying, pasting into Excel from the other application. I already have that process down, but I am needing advice on how I can paste into whatever cell is currently active, tab right, and at the end of that row go down one row, then start back in column `D`. Actually, here is a list of the exact process I am needing to happen inside the Excel application:

1. [Number Format] Paste into currently active cell (will always be in the `D:D` column)
2. Tab right one cell
3. [Date Format: "d-mmm"] Today's Date
4. Tab Right
5. [Text] Paste
6. Tab Right
7. [Accounting] Paste
8. Tab Right
9. Type the letter "X" in that column
10. Enter down one line, starting back in the `D` column.

Between all of these steps I have the majority of that code figured out that interacts with the other application. But I do have one question in regards to that as well -- In that application I am running this statement:

`With ATC.ActiveSession` (ATC is simply referencing the application's type library to interact with other application)

As opposed to me ending the `With` statement every time the applications switch back and forth copying and pasting, what would I need to do use as a `with` statement to use excel's library?

Example of what I don't want to happen:

```
Sub New_ATS()

    Set ATC = GetObject(, "ATWin32.AccuTerm")

    AppActivate "AccuTerm 2K2"
    With ATC.ActiveSession
        .InputMode = 1
        .SetSelection 6, 15, 12, 15
        .Copy
        .InputMode = 0
    End With
    AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
        Selection.Paste '(not complete, part of question)
        Selection.Offset 1, 0 'again, part of the question
    AppActivate "AccuTerm 2K2"
    With ATC.ActiveSession
        .InputMode = 1
        .SetSelection 14, 3, 20, 3
        .Copy
        .InputMode = 0
    End With
    AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
    ' .... end of partial code (continues on)
End Sub
```

But instead, would like to 'chain' the `With` statements, but I don't know what statement I would use to point back to Excel's VBA. This is what I would like:

```
Sub New_ATS()

    Set ATC = GetObject(, "ATWin32.AccuTerm")

    AppActivate "AccuTerm 2K2"
    With ATC.ActiveSession
        .InputMode = 1
        .SetSelection 6, 15, 12, 15
        .Copy
        .InputMode = 0
        With Excels_Statement '?????
            AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
            Selection.Paste '(not complete, part of question)
            Selection.Offset 1, 0 'again, part of the question
            AppActivate "AccuTerm 2K2"
            With ATC.ActiveSession
                .InputMode = 1
                .SetSelection 14, 3, 20, 3
                .Copy
                .InputMode = 0
                With Excels_Statement '????
                    AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With

    ' .... end of partial code (continues on)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have AccuTerm installed but I think you can paste into Excel without having to activate it each time. Instead of using With blocks, you could assign an object variable with minimal typing... not the best practice for variable naming but it would do the trick. Declaring the variable of the specific type would give you access to Excel's library.

Here's what I'm thinking... (partially tested so you might have to tweak it a little)

```
Sub New_ATS()

    Set ATC = GetObject(, "ATWin32.AccuTerm")
    Dim Sesh as ATWin32.AccuTerm.Session  'Not sure this exists
    Dim XL as Excel.Range

    AppActivate "AccuTerm 2K2"
    Set Sesh = ATC.ActiveSession

    Sesh.InputMode = 1
    Sesh.SetSelection 6, 15, 12, 15
    Sesh.Copy
    Sesh.InputMode = 0

    'AppActivate "Microsoft Excel" - don't need it
    Set XL = application.activecell
    XL.PasteSpecial
    Set XL = XL.offset(0,1)

    'AppActivate "AccuTerm 2K2" - no need, still active
    Sesh.InputMode = 1               'Once this is set, do you need to set it again?
    Sesh.SetSelection 14, 3, 20, 3
    Sesh.Copy
    Sesh.InputMode = 0               'Once this is set, do you need to set it again?

    XL.PasteSpecial
    XL.NumberFormat = "General"      'Bullet #1
    Set XL = XL.offset(1,0)

    '...and so on...

    XL.PasteSpecial
    XL.NumberFormat = "d-mmm"        'Bullet #3
    Set XL = XL.offset(1,0)

    XL.PasteSpecial
    XL.NumberFormat = "@"            'Bullet #5
    Set XL = XL.offset(1,0)

    XL.PasteSpecial
    XL.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)"      'Bullet #7
    Set XL = XL.offset(1,0)

    XL = "X"                          'Bullet #9

    'When you've reached the end of the row
    Set XL = XL.offset(1, 4 - XL.Column)  'Since col D = 4
    'And repeat your procedure

End Sub
```